# Returning constructor function does not produce constructor function

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype, new-operator

I want to create an ad-hoc constructor with the following code,

```
    var foo = function() {
        var bar = {
        a : 3,
        b : {c: 4, d: {e: 5}}
        };

        var f_ = function() {};

        f_.prototype = bar;

        return f_;
    }
```

From my understanding, `foo` should return a function that can be used as a constructor, like so `var baz = new foo` However, the constructor returns a function, not an object. I can see prototype from the function returned,

```
    >baz.prototype
    { a: 3, b: { c: 4, d: { e: 5 } } }
```

So, my question is, why isn't `foo` returning a constructor?

Comment: should be `baz = new (foo());`, `new foo` creates an instance of foo, and not an instance of the function returned by foo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a slight modification to your code. If you want `foo` to be a constructor function then make sure it's an immediate function in the first place, which returns a new constructor function:

```js
var foo = function() {
    var bar = {
        a: 3,
        b: {c: 4, d: {e: 5}}
    };

    var f_ = function() {};

    f_.prototype = bar;

    return f_;
}(); 

var obj = new foo();

alert(obj.a + ', ' + obj.b.d.e)
```

Note, `()` at the end of the `foo` function, those parentesis make `foo` execute immediately and assign new function `f_` to it.

Comment: I tested this and it worked but I thought `foo` was returning the constructor function itself. Why do I have to execute the return value to get it? Wouldn't I just be executing the return value of `function() {}` which is undefined?

Comment: *"I thought foo was returning the constructor function itself."* Yes, correct, `foo` returns a constructor function, but you need to call it first. Without immediate invocation like in my answer you can use it like this `var obj = new foo()()`. But it's not that convenient.